# Empty Space between Pager and ViewPanel

Tags: xpages

I need to remove unnecess[ary empty slot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlevD.png)s which is shown on the picture attached. is it property of pager and viewPanel that cannot be removed or it is possiblle to remove with CSS or anything else...

Regards
Cumhur

Comment: You need to use CSS to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative top-margin in your style.